# Refill Epson Ecotank

Tags: printer, epson-ecotank

I recently bought a new Epson Ecotank printer (ET2820). It came with four ink bottles that have some mechanism that stops the flow of ink once the tank is full. I filled all four tanks as instructed, leaving me with a small remainder in each bottle.

I have since done some printing and I think that the tanks would now be able to fit the remaining ink, so I could get rid of the bottles. However, the refill instructions state that one should fill the tank to the top and then reset the ink monitor, but I doubt that I would reach 100% with the remaining ink.

So, does anyone have experience with this series of printer? Is it safe to simply fill some ink and then continue printing until the level reaches low? Or do I have to wait for the level to go low and then use that ink in the next full refill as mentioned in the setup instructions?

Comment: It is safe to go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you keep ink above 1/3 of each tank's volume, there should be no issue with printing or copying, and you may safely ignore any warnings due to the ink meter not being reset.

However, [do not attempt Power Cleaning](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/et-2820_series/useg/en/GUID-C439F007-F647-49A6-BEEF-0BA479FFE3F3.htm) unless all tanks are at least 1/3 full: "Visually check all ink tanks are at least a third full. Low ink levels during Power Cleaning could damage the product." BTW, I find cleaning is needed more often for machines with infrequent usage.